# Manga featuring a giant blonde goddess with red lipstick who has to team up with a human

Tags: story-identification, manga

It’s been a while since I’ve seen this manga, and I meant to read it later then forgot about it. It features a giant blonde woman with red lipstick, and I believe she has to team up with a human. The art style somewhat reminds me of Monster Collection: Majuu Tsukai no Shoujo, or Saint Seiya. I keep getting Oh My Goddess! when I try to search it, but that’s not it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, roughly how tall was the giant blonde woman?

Comment: And do you remember what it was that she had to do with the team-up?  Did they have to fight the Demon Army? Solve local domestic problems? Have beautiful children? Make humans decent enough that Hell is not overloaded?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Maybe she just needed help eating all her vegetables so she could avoid being sent to bed without dessert.

Comment: @DavidW: :-D I didn't know about that manga. Wouldn't surprise me though.